# Angular 6 http request for part of large form

Tags: angular, angular-forms, angular-httpclient

I have a large form on my SPA.(person.firstName, lastName, DOB, Gender, Citizenship, etc...). I need to send to back-end for business logic validation each part of this form(which are grouped by their scope), when it was populated.

For ex: send entire form when firstName and lastName are `touched` and `valid`, and other part of form is `pristine` or `valid`. And apply the same approach for other groups.

```
<form [formGroup]="fmdForm" novalidate>
        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="col">
            <label for="prefix">Prefix</label>
            <select formControlName="party.prefix" id="prefix" >
              <option [value]="availablePrefix" *ngFor="let availablePrefix of availablePrefixes">{{availablePrefix}}
              </option>
            </select>
          </div>

          <div class="col">
            <label for="firstName">First Name<span style="color: red"> *</span> </label>
            <input formControlName="party.firstName" type="text" autocomplete="off" id="firstName"/>
          </div>

          <div class="col">
            <label for="middleName">Middle Name</label>
            <input formControlName="party.middleName" type="text" autocomplete="off" id="middleName" maxlength="1" />
          </div>

          <div class="col">
            <label for="lastName">Last Name<span style="color: red"> *</span> </label>
            <input formControlName="party.lastName" type="text" autocomplete="off" id="lastName"/>
          </div>

          <div class="col">
            <label for="suffix">Suffix</label>
            <select formControlName="party.suffix" id="suffix">
              <option [value]="availableSuffix" *ngFor="let availableSuffix of availableSuffixes">{{availableSuffix}}
              </option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
```

It is the small example of my form, which should submitted groups `prefix, firstName`, `middleName`, `lastName, suffix`.

thank you for any help

UPDATE:

my question is how I can observe whole form changes and get from this observation 2 things:

- formControl with it's current status
- current value for handled formControl

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow, your post have no question, and you don't provide any code who show us what you have already try so far

Comment: You might want to look into the official documentation. The people here can't code the logic for you. Forms come with observables that you can subscribe to them.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's not clear what you exactly want (well, it actually looks like you want someone to code it for you), I can only offer SO much guidance. You can subscribe to changes on your form by using... Observables. They're a powerful tool to keep track of changes happening in the background. It could be looking like this...

```
ngOnChanges(): void {
    this.queryForm.controls[this.queryConditionsS].valueChanges.takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe).subscribe(val => {
      this.queryFormObserver = val;
      // console.log(this.queryFormObserver);
    })
  }
```

In my case, I wanted to check what options my dynamically generated select boxes held. So I stored them in an Array, so I could always filter through the available options, since each choice had to be selected ONLY once.

Of course, there is not much you can't do in regards of your form. Of course you can also keep track of the current state of each of your fields.

https://angular.io/guide/forms

While I don't consult the official documentation for all problems, forms are fairly well explained.